# Connecting to a remote jabber server with a javascript chat client (jsjac)

Tags: javascript, xmpp

This is more of a conceptual question.

I'm trying to create a Javascript jabber client that can be installed on any arbitrary page (on x.com and y.com), and I'd like this client to be able to communicate with a remote jabber server (chatserver.com).

According to the readme of one javascript client I'm lookign at (jsjac), it is an inherent limitation of javascript that it can't communicate with a remote server due to cross site issues.

I'd appreciate hearing from anyone about how to overcome this hurdle.  A pointer to an example would be extremely helpful.

[Update] I'm assuming here that I have no control over x.com and y.com, the client servers.  The folks at Hab.la seem to have pulled this off, not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way around this is to proxy the requests from the JavaScript client to the remote server, via the server that hosts the client.

Apache's mod_proxy extension handles this fine.

Comment: Thanks Jon.  What if I don't control the client server (i.e. the chat widget is a javascript that can be inserted by anyone).  The folks at Hab.la seem to have pulled it off, not sure how they did.

Comment: Perhaps they're using dynamically generated script tags, or an IFRAME, both of which methods can be used to contact different hosts.